# How to put a title in the first column using Vuetify.js's v-simple-table?

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to use v-simple-tble, a UI component of Vuetify.js, creating a table like following table.

[image: img]

I created the following code using codesandbox and checked the screen.
As shown in the picture below, the title is displayed out of alignment.
HTML↓

```
    <div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-simple-table>
      <template v-slot:default>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-left">
              Name
            </th>
            <th class="text-left">
              Calories
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr
            v-for="item in desserts"
            :key="item.name"
          > 
            <th>{{ item.id }}</th>
            <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.calories }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </template>
    </v-simple-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Vue.js↓

```
    new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      desserts: [
        {
          id:1,
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
        },
        {
          id:2,
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
        },
        {
          id:3,
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
        },
        {
          id:4,
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
        },
        {
          id:5,
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
        },        
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

output image↓
[image: output]

Could anyone advise me?

Comment: Well .you have three columns in the tbody and only two in the thead - simply adding a column in the thead would probably do what you want - `<th>&nbsp;</th>` (non breaking space since tables can be weird with empty cells - but possibly not needed - doesn't hurt

Comment: actually, I just tried it ... all you need is `<th/>` before `<th class="text-left">Name</th>`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I really appreciated!!

Comment: If you have a any time, please give me your comment as an answer and I would like to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only two "cells" in the thead but three in the tbody

Simply add another "cell" in the thead

```
<v-simple-table>
  <template v-slot:default>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th /> <!-- added empty header to re-align columns -->
        <th class="text-left">
          Name
        </th>
        <th class="text-left">
          Calories
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr
        v-for="item in desserts"
        :key="item.name"
      > 
        <th>{{ item.id }}</th>
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.calories }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </template>
</v-simple-table>
```